# Yahoo Pipes image size filter

Tags: regex, image, url-rewriting, rss, yahoo-pipes

I have an RSS feed http://www.pinterest.com/ohjoy/recipes/rss and I am looking for a filter that could in example reject any post from my feed if image is more than 500 pixels wide or if height is less than 100 pixels. How could I do this with Yahoo Pipes?

I have tried using regex but I am not sure what to put in ther.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Pipes has no function to check image dimensions. But if you can find or create yourself a web service that checks an image specified by a URL and returns the dimensions, then you could use that, by putting an **XPath Fetch Page** inside a **Loop** operator, and assign the results to an item field.

It's entirely doable, but I don't know such web service. You could implement such service, for example based on the C# code [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4621212/641955).

Answer (score 0):

The feed from Pinterest is giving you all images that are 192px wide, instead of the original size of the image.  So you might be ok just using those instead of having to filter them.